# How to set JVM argument of Doracle.jdbc.autocommitspecCompliant= true

Tags: weblogic12c

I wanted to set  Doracle.jdbc.autocommitspecCompliant= true in weblogic. How can I achieve this in my server. I have tried in console by setting in the argument in Environment- server start set up. But it seems its not working. Can anyone help here.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? Post your full `server start` arguments here so we can see if there is anything wrong? Also check the `server.out` for the JVM start parameters.

Comment: Its not working because the funcionality of its seems not working. That is its should auto commit as per the property but its not happening. I have defined this in console of weblogic. Rest all properties are in setDomain file.

Comment: Please edit your original question and show us the full argument of the `server start`.

Comment: Doracle.jdbc.autocommitspecCompliant= true is the only argument I mentioned in server start. Is there any other way to do that.

Comment: The reason why I want to see it is so that we can help you. We don't know if you have a leading `-` in front of the `Doracle` nor do we know if you have a space between the `=` and `true`. So unless you provide more info, we really can't help you here. In fact, you may even be putting the arguments in the `classpath` instead of the `arguments` block. So many permutations.